# Python if and else , instantiation with in them?

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a file, and trying to either get the file name from user or privide a default file already exits called `word_count.txt`:

```
fname = ""
question = raw_input("Enter y if you would like to use a sample text file or n if you would like use your own")

if question == "y":
    print "ui"
    fname = "Word_count.txt"

elif question == "n":
    fname = raw_input('Enter the name of the file to be used: ')

else:
    print "lame"
```

However `fname` won't instaniate, I cant seem to get to the rest of the code?

Why is this happening, if I enter `y` it should go and hit the following lines:

```
infile = open(fname, 'r')
for line in infile:
```

Comment: The age old Python question...is your indentation correct?

Comment: Also, where is `infile = ...` in relation to the rest of the code. Could it be in the `else` block?

Comment: indentation is all correct, it runs when in ide

Comment: There is something wrong with the indentation.

Comment: @purple_rein the fact that it runs does not mean that the indentation is correct. IF it is correct, you copy+pasted it wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted works like a charm: https://repl.it/BUdZ/2

However, there are more pythonic ways for letting the `raw_input` function having a default value. One of them could be:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter a file name [default: Word_count.txt]:") or "Word_count.txt"
```

How does it work? Well, if you just press enter in the prompt of the `raw_input` function the function will return None and so the statement after `or` is evaluated which means the string `Word_count.txt` is assign to the `fname` variable. If you enter something in the prompt the `or` all other values of the condition do not get evaluated because you just need one value of an `or` to be true and so the return value is assign to `fname`.